# Not inquiring into heresy?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

Is there some sort of injunction against inquiring into heresy? I am pretty sure there is an issur d'oraissa to inquire into Avodah Zarah?

Thank you

(By "inquire" I mean to investigate their beliefs etc., similar as the injunction against inquiring into the beliefs/practices of idol worshippers.)

Comment: Look at the Koteret to Yesodei HaTorah.

Answer (score 1):

(from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heresy_in_Judaism#Talmudic_definition_of_heresy)

The Mishnah (Sanh. x. 1) says the following have no share in the world to come: "He who denies that the Torah is divinely revealed [lit. "comes from Heaven"], and the apiḳoros." R. Akiba says, "also he who reads heretical books" ("sefarim ḥiẓonim"). This is explained in the Talmud (Sanh. 100b) to mean "sifre Ẓeduḳim" (Sadducean writings); but this is an alteration by the censor of "sifre ha-Minim" (books of the Gnostics or Heretics). The Biblical version, "That ye seek not after your own heart" (Num. xv. 39), is explained (Sifre, Num. 115; Ber. 12b) as "Ye shall not turn to heretic views ["minut"] which lead your heart away from God" (see Maimonides, Yad, Akkum, ii. 3).

Comment: Also, you might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78214/on-the-study-of-philosophy/130376#130376) question about the study of philosophy. I have since seen the Be'er Sheva in Sanhedrin (100b) who speaks at length about this topic. I will quote his original question and his answer, leaving out his hava aminas, but it's worthwhile to check out the whole thing.

> תנא בספרי מינין כו'. בירושלמי (אמצע הלכה א') איתא, רבי עקיבא אומר אף
> הקורא בספרים החיצונים כגון ספר בן סירא וספרי בן לענה, אבל ספרי המירוס
> וכל ספרים שנכתבו מכאן ואילך הקורא בהן כקורא באגרת, מאי טעמא ויותר מהמה
> בני הזהר וגו' (קהלת יב, יב) להגיון ניתנו ליגיעה לא ניתנו ע"כ. משמע
> שספרי בן סירא ובן לענה אסורים אפילו להגיון בעלמא, אבל מבן סירא ובן
> לענה ואילך הותרו להגיון ולא ליגיעה. וקשה בעיני טובא, חדא הלא חכמי
> הגמרא עצמם הן בירושלמי הן בבבלי הביאו כמה דברים של בן סירא, כגון בפ"ב
> דחגיגה (יג, א), ובפ"ו דיבמות (סג, ב), ובפרק שני דייני גזירות (כתובות
> קי, ב), ובפרק המוכר פירות (ב"ב צח, ב), ובפרק מי שמת (שם קמו, א) וכהנה
> רבות (נדה טז, ב), עד כי רש"י בההיא דעירובין פרק הדר (עירובין סה, א
> עי"ש בתוס') בצר אל יורה, כתב וז"ל בדקתי אחר מקרא זה בכל הכתובים ושמא
> בספר בן סירא הוא, וכן כתבו התוס' בפרק החובל (ב"ק צב, ב ד"ה משולש
> בכתובים) על ההיא דכל עוף למינו ישכון ובן אדם לדומה לו, וכן תמצא
> בירושלמי דנזיר פרק בית שמאי (הלכה ג') ובברכות פרק ג' שאכלו (הלכה ג')
> וכהנה רבות שהביא דברי בן סירא, א"כ בהכרח למדום הימנו. ועוד קשה היאך
> מיקל יותר בספרי מירוס מבספרי בן סירא, הלא אדרבה איפכא מסתברא, כי ספרי
> מירוס הם ספרי מינים, כדתנן בהדיא בפרק בתרא דמסכת ידים (משנה ו'), ואלו
> ספר בן סירא אין בו דברי מינות אלא דברי הבאי ובא עליהם לידי ביטול,
> כדמוכח בהדיא בשמעתין, וכן פירשו רש"י (ד"ה רב יוסף) והרי"ף (יט, ב)
> והרא"ש (סימן ג') בהדיא, וז"ל אף בספר בן סירא שיש בו דברי הבאי שאין בהן
> צורך כו':
>
> ונ"ל שהרמב"ם ז"ל וסייעתו סמכו על המשנה בפ"ב דאבות (משנה י"ד) דקתני רבי
> אלעזר אומר הוי שקוד ללמוד תורה ודע מה שתשיב לאפיקורוס ודע לפני מי אתה
> עמל כו', ומייתי לה לעיל בפרק אחד דיני ממונות (לח, ב), וא"ר יוחנן עלה
> לא שנו אלא אפיקורוס עבודה זרה אבל אפיקורוס ישראל כל שכן דפקר טפי. כתב
> הרמב"ם בפירוש המשנה (אבות שם) וז"ל ואמרו אף על פי שתלמוד דעות האומות
> לדעת איך תשיב עליהם השמר שלא יעלה בלבך דבר מן הדעות ההם, ודע שמי
> שתעבוד לפניו יודע צפון לבך, והוא אמרו ודע לפני מה אתה עמל, רצה לומר
> שיכוין לבו באמונת השי"ת עכ"ל. הרי גילה דעתו מבוארת ומבוררת בכוונת
> המשנה זו, שצוה התנא שילמוד דעות האפיקורסין ויהא שקוד ללמוד תורה, כדי
> שידע מה ישיב להם על דעותיהם:

In summary, he was bothered by the following question, Rabbi Akiva says that one who reads "sefarim hachitzonim" loses his portion in olam haba, and examples of sefarim hachitzonim are sefarim "Ben Sira" and "Ben La'ana". However, we see in many places in the gemara where sefer Ben Sira is brought down, which obviously means that the chachmei hatalmud had read this book. We also see that some of the rishonim have read the book. What could their heter have been?! The Be'er Sheva answers that the mishna in pirkei avos allows one to read such book in order to know what to respond to heretics.

Here is the Rambam's peirush to that mishna:

> למד דברים שתשיב בהם על האפיקורוסים מן האומות, ותתווכח עמהם ותענה להם אם יקשו לך. ואמרו: "לא שנו אלא אפיקורוס גוי, אבל ישראל כל שכן דפקר", רצונו לומר: שהוא יוסיף זלזול ולגלוג, ולפיכך אין ראוי לדון עמו כלל, לפי שהוא לא יתוקן, ואין לו רפואה כלל, "כל באיה לא ישובון ולא י(ס)[ש]יגו אורחות חיים" +משלי ב יט+. ואמר, ועם היותך לומד דעות האומות כדי שתדע איך תשיב עליהם, היזהר שלא ידבק בדעתך דבר מזה, ודע כי אשר תעבוד לפניו ידע צפונותיך, והוא אומרו: ודע לפני מי אתה עמל.

The main point in the Rambam that I wanted to bring down is that one should study these types of books, but one should also be careful not to let it slip too far, and one should always delineate between that which he believes and that which he knows in order to answer heretics.

(Derech Agav, I've seen the Medresh Shmuel on this mishna in avos say that the way one should study these ideas is certainly not on a superficial level, because then one won't be able to hold his own in a real debate. Rather, one must study these ideas and incorporate them into his own knowledge as well as any other topic and really make it his own.)

Comment: Gut moed! You have provided a number of answers recently all of which are of sound logic. However, please note that there a large number of Mi Yodeya users that can't read Hebrew let alone translate it. It is always best practise to at the very least provide a summary of what each quote is, or ideally to provide a translation. Hatzlocho.

Comment: @Dov Thank you and gut moed! Okay, I'll will - bli neder - make sure to do so in the future.

Comment: shkoiach! Keep shteiging!

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned, the verse says in Deut. 12:

כט  כִּי-יַכְרִית יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ אֶת-הַגּוֹיִם, אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה בָא-שָׁמָּה לָרֶשֶׁת אוֹתָם--מִפָּנֶיךָ; וְיָרַשְׁתָּ אֹתָם, וְיָשַׁבְתָּ בְּאַרְצָם.   29

When/because/definitely Hashem your God shall cut off the nations from before you, where you go in to dispossess them, and you shall dispossess them, and dwell in their land;

ל  הִשָּׁמֶר לְךָ, פֶּן-תִּנָּקֵשׁ אַחֲרֵיהֶם, אַחֲרֵי, הִשָּׁמְדָם מִפָּנֶיךָ; וּפֶן-תִּדְרֹשׁ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם לֵאמֹר, אֵיכָה יַעַבְדוּ הַגּוֹיִם הָאֵלֶּה אֶת-אֱלֹהֵיהֶם, וְאֶעֱשֶׂה-כֵּן, גַּם-אָנִי.

30 take heed to yourself that your **be not ensnared to follow them, after that they are destroyed from before thee; and that you inquire not after their gods, saying: 'How used these nations to serve their gods? even so will I do likewise.'**

לא  לֹא-תַעֲשֶׂה כֵן, לַיהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ:  כִּי כָל-תּוֹעֲבַת יְהוָה אֲשֶׁר שָׂנֵא, עָשׂוּ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם--כִּי גַם אֶת-בְּנֵיהֶם וְאֶת-בְּנֹתֵיהֶם, יִשְׂרְפוּ בָאֵשׁ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם.

31 You shalt not do so unto Hashem your God; for every abomination to the LORD, which He hateth, have they done unto their gods; for even their sons and their daughters do they burn in the fire to their gods.

Among other verses.

---

Now, beyond straight up idolatry, even works of philosophy and even rationalistic philosophical approaches to the Torah that have entered our Rabbinic literature for whatever reason, are a severe, severe prohibition - so all the more so the ways of heresy God forbid - except only certain extraordinary Tzaddikim needed to descend into them for specific reasons on "special missions" to repair "souls" and extricate holiness, and repair and redeem things - per Likutei Moharan #64.

https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Etzot%2C_Philosophy_and_Secular_Wisdom.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

ט. אִסּוּר גָּדוֹל לְעַיֵּן בְּסִפְרֵי הַמְחַקְּרִים. כִּי יֵשׁ כַּמָּה קֻשְׁיוֹת שֶׁנִּמְשָׁכִין מִבְּחִינַת חָלָל הַפָּנוּי שֶׁאִי אֶפְשָׁר לִמְצֹא עֲלֵיהֶם תֵּרוּץ בְּשׁוּם אֹפֶן, רַק לֶעָתִיד לָבוֹא יִתְגַּלֶּה הַתֵּרוּץ, אֲבָל בְּזֶה הָעוֹלָם אִי אֶפְשָׁר לְיַשְּׁבָם בְּשׁוּם שֵׂכֶל. וּמִי שֶׁמְּעַיֵּן בְּאֵלּוּ הַחָכְמוֹת הַנִּמְשָׁכִין מִשָּׁם, יִהְיֶה נִשְׁקָע וְנֶאֱבָד שָׁם לְעוֹלָם, כִּי עָלֶיהָ נֶאֱמַר: "כָּל בָּאֶיהָ לֹא יְשׁוּבוּן". כִּי אִי אֶפְשָׁר לִמְצֹא בָּהֶם אֶת הַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ וּלְהָשִׁיב עַל הַקֻּשְׁיוֹת וְהַמְּבוּכוֹת שֶׁבָּהֶם בְּשׁוּם שֵׂכֶל. רַק יִשְׂרָאֵל, עַל־יְדֵי אֱמוּנָה עוֹבְרִים עַל כָּל הַחָכְמוֹת וְעַל כָּל הַמְּבוּכוֹת שֶׁבָּעוֹלָם. כִּי הֵם מַאֲמִינִים בְּהַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ וּבְתוֹרָתוֹ הַקְּדוֹשָׁה בְּלִי שׁוּם חֲקִירָה וְחָכְמָה, רַק בֶּאֱמוּנָה שְׁלֵמָה. וְעַל שֵׁם זֶה נִקְרָאִים יִשְׂרָאֵל "עִבְרִים", עַל שֶׁעַל־יְדֵי אֱמוּנָתָם הֵם עוֹבְרִים וְעוֹלִים עַל כָּל מִינֵי חָכְמוֹת וַחֲקִירוֹת. כִּי אֵינָם צְרִיכִים לַחֲקֹר אַחַר הָאֱמֶת כְּלָל, כִּי הֵם יוֹדְעִים הָאֱמֶת לַאֲמִתּוֹ עַל־יְדֵי אֱמוּנָתָם הַשְּׁלֵמָה, שֶׁמַּאֲמִינִים בְּהָאֱמֶת כְּפִי מַה שֶּׁקִּבְּלוּ מֵאֲבוֹתֵינוּ וְרַבּוֹתֵינוּ זַ"ל. וְעַל־יְדֵי זֶה הֵם עוֹבְרִים וְעוֹלִים עַל כָּל הַחָכְמוֹת כֻּלָּם: (לק"א סי' ס"ד אות ב')

**It is forbidden to delve into philosophical works.** There are certain questions which stem from the chalal hapanui, “the empty void,” to which it is impossible to find any answer. In time to come the answers will be revealed. But in this world it is impossible to put these questions to rest merely with thought and ingenuity. Whole philosophical systems have been built up around them. **Anyone who delves into them will be sunk in them and lost eternally, as it is written: “None that go unto her return” (Proverbs 2:19). God is not to be found in these philosophies. Through intelligence alone it will never be possible to solve the intellectual tangles they contain. The Jewish people, with its faith in God, is beyond all these philosophies and their complications. Israel believes in God and His Holy Torah without needing philosophical justifications. They have pure faith. The Hebrew word for “beyond” is עבר, e-ver, and the Jews are called עברים, Ivrim — Hebrews — precisely because they are beyond all this speculation. With a faith which transcends philosophy we do not need to speculate about the truth. We know it. We have received it from our fathers, of blessed memory (Likutei Moharan 64:2).**

י. וְדַע, שֶׁיֵּשׁ צַדִּיקִים גְּדוֹלִים שֶׁהֵם צְרִיכִין דַּוְקָא לְעַיֵּן בְּאֵלּוּ הַחָכְמוֹת, כִּי עַל יְדֵי עִיּוּנָם בָּהֶם הֵם מַעֲלִין וּמוֹצִיאִין מֵהֶם כַּמָּה נְשָׁמוֹת שֶׁנָּפְלוּ וְנִשְׁקְעוּ בָּהֶם. וְעַל־כֵּן אַל תָּבִיא לְךָ רְאָיָה מִמַּה שֶּׁמָּצִינוּ כַּמָּה גְּדוֹלֵי הַקַּדְמוֹנִים שֶׁעָסְקוּ בְּאֵלּוּ הַחָכְמוֹת, כִּי הָיוּ מֻכְרָחִים לָזֶה כַּנַּ"ל. וּלְגֹדֶל קְדֻשָּׁתָם הָעֲצוּמָה הֶעֱלוּ נְשָׁמוֹת שֶׁנָּפְלוּ בָּהֶם, כַּנַּ"ל. אֲבָל אֲנָשִׁים שֶׁאֵינָם גְּדוֹלִים בְּצִדְקוּת כָּל כָּךְ, מִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן אֲנָשִׁים פְּשׁוּטִים, בִּפְרָט בַּדּוֹרוֹת הַלָּלוּ, חָלִילָה לְהִסְתַּכֵּל וְלִכְנֹס בָּהֶם, כִּי יִהְיֶה נִשְׁקָע וְנֶאֱבָד שָׁם לְעוֹלָם רַחֲמָנָא לִצְלָן: (שם אות ג')

**Certain of the great Tzaddikim were obliged to go into these philosophies in order to extricate and elevate the souls which have fallen and become sunk in them. You cannot argue that it is permissible for others to enter them on the grounds that many of the great scholars of the past were involved. In their case it was an obligation. And through the great sanctity they possessed, they had the power to release the souls which were trapped. But people who are not on a comparable level of sanctity, and needless to add, the ordinary people of our own age, should never enter these realms and risk being eternally lost (Ibid. 3).**

יא. עַל־יְדֵי הַנִּגּוּן שֶׁל הַצַּדִּיק הַגָּדוֹל הָאֲמִתִּי, הוּא מַעֲלֶה הַנְּשָׁמוֹת שֶׁנָּפְלוּ לָאֶפִּיקוֹרְסוּת הַנַּ"ל שֶׁאֵין עָלֶיהָ תְּשׁוּבָה: (שם אות ה')

The song of the true Tzaddik has the power to draw up the souls that have fallen into this form of atheism, from which there is otherwise no return (Ibid. 5).

---

See also Chayey Moharan #407 ff.

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Chayey_Moharan#%5B%23407-425%5D_Keeping_Far_Away_from_Chaqirot_%28philosophy%3B_rationalism%3B_undermining_or_questioning_the_tenets_of_faith%29_and_Staying_Strong_in_Emunah_%28Faith%29

#407

407
About **the philosophical books**  he told us a great deal, many times. And he **utterly, utterly forbade us to even look at them at all, God forbid. He put extraordinary stress on the severity of this prohibition, because they very much confuse one's religious views with alien views that do not at all agree at all with the views of our Holy Torah.** They [the authors of these philosophical books] also do not believe in demons whereas all the words of the Talmudic Sages say the opposite. Especially now that we've been privileged to [the revelation of] the Zohar, the books of the Arizal and the Baal Shem Tov of blessed memory and so forth, which are all founded on Ruach Hakodesh and greatly inspire a person in truly serving His Blessedness.

...

Comment: This is only applicable to Breslev chassidim. Mainstream yeshivish rabbanim will tell you to read Rambam and Kuzari and avoid Likutei Moharan.