# On the Study of Philosophy

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

Is the study of philosophy (particularly Greek philosophy including physics and metaphysics) forbidden, permitted, encouraged, or discouraged? Specifically what are the views of Geonim and Rishonim on this? (Based on direct evidence of their own writings; not based on secondary or tertiary sources.)

One possibly related source is the Gemara Menahot 99b, in which Ben Dama asks R. Yishmael if he may study hokhma yevanit; a possible reference to Greek philosophy, and R. Yishamel forbids this.

Do different subsets of philosophy have different statuses?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23298/1857 related

Comment: See Sotah 49b and Rashi there. Its a good starting point.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-much-greek-in-greek-wisdom-on.html

Comment: Commentless downvoter??

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82599/1857

Comment: This was a major dispute, especially in regards to writings of Rambam.

Comment: The kabbalists are famously anti the study of philosophy, but you'll mostly get acharonim speaking about it because of that. E.g. I recall seeing very strong language against the study of philosophy from the Leshem, but I'd have to look up exactly where it is.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120119122828/http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-much-greek-in-greek-wisdom-on.html

Answer (score 4):

This answer is reposted from [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127408/may-one-study-medieval-christian-philosophers-such-as-augustine-or-aquinas).

I know someone who asked Rav Mordechai Willig about reading the Book of Mormon and he said no.

For further reading see the first mishna in perek cheilek (that would be the 10th perek in Sanhedrin) and in the Rambam and Bartenura on the line from R' Akiva, "Even one who reads seforim chitzonim [has no chelek to olam habah]". These meforshim explain that the problem is one of complete waste of time, and therefore the Bartenura says in maseches avos (5:22) that it is permitted to read these books in the restroom because there it is asur to think in Torah. According to this, given that everyone wastes so much time with useless stuff anyway, there would seem to be a strong leg to stand on from here to say it's permissible.

Also see shu"t Rashba chelek aleph simanim 414-418 (warning, 418 is very, very long) about what is seemingly the same topic where he is quite machmir.

There is also a teshuva of the Rivash (chelek aleph siman 45) which is very helpful, where he speaks out his view of chachmas yevanis (lit. Greek wisdom) as well as that of Rashi and the Rambam, ע"ש. He brings sources from chazal that chochmas yevanis is real bad, however, he describes it not as philosophical or theological works, but as speaking in riddles, ע"ש. Based on this as well it would seem to be permissible.

I also know that a prominent Rosh Yeshiva in E"Y read Thomas Aquinas in university for the purpose of writing a paper on the existence of God.

EDIT: However, see Yoreh De'ah siman 246 sif 4 and the Shach there sif katan 6 who bolsters the Rama and says not to study such things until one is well versed in all areas of Torah.

However, please do not rely on this, go and ask someone who actually knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As brought in the Gemara, the Sage turned apostate Acher, his downfall was because a Greek melody was always in his mouth.

If something so seemingly neutral as a melody can do that, then philosophy and sciences how much more.

However regarding music, one of the Seven Chokhmot (wisdoms/philosophies/sciences) there's an advice. And that is too learn the Oral Torah at night. This helps protect against the hearing of such music, per Likutei Moharan 3. R' Nachman said severe warnings against Chokhmot Chitzoniyot; perhaps this advice extends to help against the damage of the other Chokhmot as well if there's a necessity for them.

https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.3.1?lang=bi

Comment: This doesn’t seem to directly address the question, especially the line “Specifically what are the views of Geonim and Rishonim on this?”.