# What are Sifrei Minim today?

Tags: halacha, books-generally, olam-haba-world-to-come, heresy, maseches-sanhedrin

In Sanhedrin 100b: Rabbi Akivah says "Even one who reads foreign Seforim (has no chelek in Olam Haba)". Beraitha there: "He refers to Sifrei Tzedukim" (or "Sifrei Minim" according to all of the old, uncensored manuscripts) [src](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/insites/sn-dt-100.htm) (Likewise, this Girsa of Sifrei Minim is brought in Shaarei Kedusha gate 2).

What would constitute Sifrei Minim today according to halacha? Looking for a clear guideline. would this also include things like books championing atheism such as Dawkins' books?

Comment: Ein Mishpat there references a ruling of Maimonides. Did you look there? Did you do any sort of research? If so, it should be edited into the OP.

Comment: "what would constitute sifrei minim today? looking for a clear guideline" Is there any reason to assume the the guideline of this halakha is any different today from what it ever was?

Comment: Do we Paskin like R Akiva here?

Comment: @DoubleAA who said anything about halacha

Comment: @ray I guess Isaac did when he added the tag halacha. But certainly this question is more interesting if the definition is relevant halachically

Comment: @DoubleAA "Do we Paskin like R Akiva here" - havent seen any opinion in the talmud which permits them

Comment: @ray Permitting something and declaring someone who reads it a heretic are different things.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%95_%D7%93

Answer (score 4):

Rashi on the Daf (S.V Rav Yosef) says that the Sifrei Minim ie. Sefer Ben Sira is called a Sefer Min:

> שיש בו דברי הבאי ובא עליהם לידי ביטול תורה

Because it has Divrei Havai - empty things, and they cause Bittul Torah.

Rav Yaakov Kaminetzky basing himself off Rashi's interpretation is qouted saying that any book that leads to Bittul Torah is classified as a Sefer Min.

The Rambam as well, in his commentary to the Mishna, also classifies books that are wasteful as Sifrei Minim:

> ובספרים החיצונים אמרו שהם ספרי תועים (סנהדרין ק ע"ב) וכן ספר בן סירא
>   והוא היה איש שחיבר ספרים יש בהם היתולים מענייני הכרת, פנים אין בהם טעם
>   ולא תועלת, אלא איבוד הזמן בהבל. כגון **אלה הספרים הנמצאים אצל הערב מספור
>   דברי הימים והנהגות המלכים וייחוסי הערבים וספרי הניגון וכיוצא בהן מן
>   הספרים שאין בהם חכמה ולא תועלת גופני, אלא איבוד הזמן בלבד**

The Bartenura on the Mishna defines Sifrei Minim as the books of Aristotle the Greek and his friends:

> כגון אריסט״ו היוני וחביריו

Though the Rav allows it in the bathroom or the Bath House.

Comment: Note, however, that in Mishneh Torah, the closest he comes to describing this is Hilkhot Avoda Zara (2:2) which has a much narrower scope.