# Which Divrei Minus are forbidden to read/hear today?

Tags: avodah-zarah, talmud-bavli, heresy

The Talmud in (Avodah Zara [16b](http://halakhah.com/zarah/zarah_16.html#PARTb)–[17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.16b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) brings that Rabbi Eliezer was upset that he had been accused by the Romans. His student, Rabbi Akiva suggested that perhaps he had heard a teaching of the *minim* and got pleasure from the teaching Rabbi Eliezer confirmed this.

According to this, what would constitute "teachings of the *minim"* which is forbidden to read or hear or watch, etc. today?

Comment: Have you seen Rambam Hilchot Avodah Zarah 2:2 and Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 143:15?

Comment: "today"? Has the prohibition changed?

Comment: Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82585/what-are-sifrei-minim-today Or are you specifically distinguishing between a Teaching" of minus and a "book" of minus?

Comment: @Alex not limited to books.